# Why GRANT, REVOKE has identified as DDL statement?

Tags: ddl, dcl

I saw this in Oracle link that GRANT and REVOKE are DDL statements:
[image]

I always thought that GRANT and REVOKE are DCL statements.
This is the link:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Types-of-SQL-Statements.html#GUID-FD9A8CB4-6B9A-44E5-B114-EFB8DA76FC88

I tried to understand, there is something i missed or i don't understand ?
Please help me to understand